# Why is my material rendering black?

Tags: rendering

Yet another newbie material not rendering question. I apologize, but I've due-diligenced myself to death looking for the solution.

I couldn't solve this problem in my actual model, so I've set up a bare test model that consists only of the cube present by default in a new model.

I've set the material as a reflective metallic object, as shown in the Material Preview.

I've put both a light in the scene, as well as an HDR environment to have something to reflect.

The rendered image shows just like the preview in the upper window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Latest drivers installed?

Comment: Fresh install of B2.83.3. All else is up to date.

Comment: I guess either your graphics card is not supported or a bug: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ so might be worth to file a bug report...

Comment: I've rendered on this laptop before with the metallic/mirrored effect without a problem. I'm a dufus, and am sure I'm just missing something obvious. Thanks.

Comment: I5 integrated graphics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/stWRQ.png no issue, try switching to cycles render. As suspected, seems to be something wrong with your drivers/hardware not being able to handle eevee preview/render. If you're sure that latest drivers installed, consider to file a bug report (Main menu > Help > Report a Bug)

Comment: Cycles is a no go :(  Unable to file Bug Report since I cannot complete the registration process. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As you can see in the image (click it), it is working in eevee on a pretty low-end machine.