# Why eevee renders reflective objects in black and cycles does not?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine, error

Eevee renders objects in black, while Cycles renders as expected. HDR is present and lights are in the scene. I'm not using any textures. Thanks for any ideas.

[image: Eevee renders with black objects.]

[image: Cycles renders as expected.]

**Q:** Why my reflective object is pitch black in eevee?

[image]

Comment: Try enabling screen-space reflections in EEVEE.

Comment: Enabling screen-space reflections in eevee did not solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: It is hard to find out what is causing the issue here. Can you provide the file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=40nGElja" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/40nGElja/)

Comment: Model behaves the same (eevee has black text, cycles has correct shiny text) whether transparency is set or not.

Comment: Works correctly for me. check your Graphics Drivers, make sure you have the latest, also try to Delete Blender and install again

Comment: Are you saying that the model, as loaded, doesn't have black text when rendered in Eevee (shiny in Cycles)?  Graphics drivers are current on both machines that show it as black. I'm already using a fresh B2.83.1, as B2.83.3 crashes frequently.

Comment: Works as expected... How this is different to [Why is my material rendering black?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189594/why-is-my-material-rendering-black) Please edit your original question using the edit button next time, Thanks. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour How to ask a good question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is different because this is describing a problem only with rendering in Eevee, since Cycles renders the material properly. Already been pinged for "having a discussion in the comments", so since this is a different problem, I made a new topic.

Comment: Have you tried the file on another machine in the meantime? Make sure your GPU meets the minimum requirements: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ Again working fine here, even on my low-end machine (i5, integrated graphics, linux). If you are on windows try a linux or report the issue as suggested before.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the `Render Properties` > [Screen space reflections](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/screen_space_reflections.html) > enable refraction.
I hope this works.

Comment: This didn't work (previously suggested above). Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that the problem discussed here, as well as other recent rendering posts, may be linked to a video issue related to recent updates.

After duplicating the issues on three computers, all of which meet the video requirements as stated by Blender documentation, I began trying several recent Blender versions. All exhibited rendering issues ***except*** Bv2.81.

Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: Certain hardware... real issue is: if no one with that graphics card, files a bug report it never get fixed.